# Using one dictionary vs. many to store program configurations

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am writing a Python program with many (approx ~30-40) parameters, all of which have default values, and all should be adjustable at run time by the user. The way I set it up, these parameters are grouped into 4 dictionaries, corresponding to 4 different modules of the program. However, I have encountered a few cases of a single parameter required by more then one of these modules, leading me to consider just unifying the dictionaries into one big config dictionary, or perhaps even one config object, passed to each module.
My questions are

1. Would this have any effect on run time? I suspect not, but want to be sure.
2. Is this considered good practice? Is there some other solution to the problem I have described?

Comment: Ideally configuration files shouldn't contain such information. The data in a config file can be environment dependent or depends on some other context. But once your application is loaded this shouldn't change. Since you want all params to be configurable by end user, so better to put them in a class and manage them using class methods. To address common variables you can use inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. probably no effect on runtime. larger dictionaries *could* take longer to lookup in, but in your case, we are talking about 40 items. that's nothing.
2. we use a single settings file in which we initialize globals by calling a method that either read the config from the environment, a file or a Python file (as globals). the method that reads the config can get the desired type and default value. Others use *YAML* or *TOML* for representing configuration and I'm guessing then stores them a globally accessible object. If your settings can be changed in runtime, you have to protect this object in terms of thread-safety (if you have threads of course).